# Warning of "Control may reach end of non-void function"

Tags: c++, xcode

I ran a C++ program in Xcode, and encountered a warning of "Control may reach end of non-void function". Here is the code:

```
Node* search(Node* head, int x)
{
    if(!head)
        return NULL;
    else if(x == head->key)
        return head;
    else if(x < head->key)
        search(head->lchild, x);
    else
        search(head->rchild, x);
}
```

I got the same warning when compiling it in Linux, but got the correct result. But in Xcode, the result was wrong. By the way, I got the correct answer and no warning in Visual Studio.

Comment: You need to return a value from every branch. If you don't, it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: You got the correct result only because you were fortunate that nothing else happened in your function after the two `search` invokes that modified EAX.  So their return value was likely still just sitting there in the EAX register. This is UB. Specify all return paths properly.

Comment: Note why it results in a correct answer under Linux and Visual Studio is explained in "[Why does a recursed return call break out of stack without an explicit return statement?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14102700/90527)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to return the result of the recursive calls:

```
Node* search(Node* head, int x)
{
    if(!head)
        return NULL;
    else if(x == head->key)
        return head;
    else if(x < head->key)
        return search(head->lchild, x);
    else
        return search(head->rchild, x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function as it is now allows you to flow off the end of the function with no explicit return which is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), the draft standard section `6.6.3` *The return statement* says;

> [...]Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.[...]

the last two *else* do not have a *return* statement:

```
 else if(x < head->key)
    search(head->lchild, x);  // No return
 else
    search(head->rchild, x);  // No return
 // no return
}
```

so in these cases you will flow off the end without returning a value and thus invoked *undefined behavior*, it seems like you probably meant to have a *return* but just left them out and really meant this:

```
else if(x < head->key)
    return search(head->lchild, x); 
else
    return search(head->rchild, x);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
else if(x < head->key)
    search(head->lchild, x);
else
    search(head->rchild, x);
```

In those branches, you're:

- calling `search` recursively
- discarding the value it returns
- not returning anything

Not returning a value from a function is Undefined Behaviour. The fact that you got correct results is purely accidental and not to be relied upon, the compiler could well choose to format your hard drive or order a pizza instead.

Fix that by adding `return` statements:

```
else if(x < head->key)
    return search(head->lchild, x);
else
    return search(head->rchild, x);
```