# Differences in compilers. C language

Tags: c, visual-studio

Why my "C" code doesn't compile in Linux (compiler ggdb3, C99) but nice work in Visual Studio?
Here message of error:

> 20:1: error: control may reach end of non-void function
>   [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
>       }

```
#include <stdio.h>
//  Function to determine if one character string exists inside another string.
int findString(char source[], char searching[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (; source[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (source[i] == searching[j])
            if (source[i + 1] == searching[j + 1] &&
                source[i + 2] == searching[j + 2])
                return i;
            else
                return -1;
    }

}

int main(void)
{
    int index = findString("a chatterbox", "hat");

    if (index == -1)
        printf("No match are founded\n");
    else
        printf("Match are founded starting index is %i\n", index);

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to edd in the function this but it doesn't help

```
if (source[0] == '\0')
        return -1;
```

Comment: Well, as the error message suggests, you forgot to insert a `return` statement at the end of `findString`. Also, the Visual Studio C/C++ compiler is more a C++ compiler than a C compiler.

Comment: every time use `Warnings as errors`. those warnings are irl errors, which you are going to face in a hard way later if you ignore them in the beginning.

Comment: Compilers don't tend to complain about such things, by default.  So it is not particularly surprising that Visual Studio doesn't.   Although linux compilers don't always diagnose such things, it is also not exactly a surprise that your "linux compiler" does, since it has been given command line options to pick up this concern and treat it as an error.   If you read the documentation for Visual Studio, you might find a comparable option or set of options.   The solution is to make sure that every execution path through the function has a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First C is not Python so you need to use brackets properly (not just indenting).

That said, the problem is with your `findString()` function. Once you do put some brackets properly, you will that `if (source[i] != searching[j])` the function does not have a `return` statement - whereas it's expected to return an `int`.

```
 if (source[i] == searching[j])
 {
     ...
 }
 // what if source[i] != searching[j]
 // you do not have any return statement for a function returning int
```

---

Failure to return from a non-void function causes undefined behaviour.

Citing C11 (by rubenvb)

> 6.9.1 Function definitions
>
> 12 If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

It's [more clear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19532322/4975822) with C++:

> [...]Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.[...]

Comment: Correction: it will not return anything; it invokes undefined behaviour, which means the program may crash, eat your children or summon kthulu.

Comment: @rubenvb true, but I haven't found the source in C standard to say so..

Comment: if you cast your children as chicken `C` will happily accept your children for  chicken. think first if you  want to do that.

Comment: @bansi sorry what's that supposed to mean here? be more specific please

Comment: What about 6.9.1/12 in C99: "If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller,the behavior is undefined." So calling such a function isn't bad in itself, only actually using the result.

Comment: @rubenvb thanks but I only have C11 draft - perhaps something similar there I guess..

Comment: @rubenvb ok found it.. - this item is exactly the same btw C99 and C11..

Comment: The location of these things doesn't normally change (much) so the numbers should be (approximately) correct regardless the version. Unless the rule changed of course ;)

Comment: @artm sry the comment was not towards your answer, it was towards the another comment/ OP's question. Basically `it means C is raw power which you should not misuse`. at-least respect compiler warnings.

Comment: Thank you @artm! I've fixed it. Now it works fine without any errors.

Comment: Braces wouldn't change anything here.

Comment: @MikeMB it's good practice in C/C++ code to add brackets especially when there are multiple levels of `if`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're actually just getting a warning, but since you've given the Linux compiler the command line argument -Werror it's treating the warning as an error. If you look in the compiler output for Visual Studio you should see a similar warning.

Comment: Look in the output window at the bottom of Visual Studio. It says "warning C4715: 'findString' not all control paths" (the rest is obscured by the command window).

Comment: I see warning C4715 Thank you! @bace1000

Comment: It's a warning, but it's pointing out an actual problem in the code so it isn't safe to ignore it.